# OSX: git: remote: Permission to user/repo denied to otheruser

Tags: git, macos, authentication, github

I am trying to push a new repo to github and am being prevented from doing so because git has cached `meatwork` credentials.

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to me/me.github.io.git denied to meatwork.
```

After some digging around, I thought maybe credential.helper was the issue, so I tried to remove it bit git config still returns osxkeychain even though I have removed all settings.

```
$ git config --system credential.helper 
$ git config --global credential.helper 
$ git config --local credential.helper 
$ git config credential.helper
osxkeychain
$
```

Also looked at git credential-osxkeychain but it just hangs

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain get
```

So anyway back to the original problem, how do I specify or override or reset the default user being used by push.  I checked the `user.name` and `user.email` settings and they are set to the correct user (not `meatwork`).

```
$ git config --local user.name
$ git config --global user.name
me
$ git config --system user.name
$ git config --local user.email
$ git config --global user.email
me@myhome.com
$ git config --system user.email
```

So where is git getting `meatwork` credentials from and how to I stop it.

Comment: I'd check whether you have any additional SSH keys in your SSH agent: `ssh-add -L`

Comment: The agent has no identities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the simple answer to the second part of my question thanks to a hint found here https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Setting the `credential.username` property for the cloned repository to the username I want to use did the trick.

```
$ git config credential.username me
```

And now my push works!  I still don't know where meatwork is coming from though.

Alternatively, editing `.git/config` and changing the `[remote "origin"] url=` to include `username@` in the URL also works.

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://me@github.com/Me/me.github.io.git
```

Answer (score 11):

my solution is (on Mac):

1. Open **Keychain Access** app.
2. Search for *github.com*
3. Delete the information of other users

And see if it works now.

My situation is, someone has used my Mac to log into his Github, and Mac remembers his name and password, which is why permission is denied to him...

---

Reference: [Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain | Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)

Comment: There isn't much in my keychain and it all looks sensible and for my accounts not meatwork, plus no one else has access to this laptop.

Comment: @AustinFrance That sounds strange!!

Comment: @AustinFrance I would recommend creating a new ssh and add it again, sometimes it's just weird that it cannot work.

Comment: At least for me this is the best answer. Changes in specific clone helped just locally. Into keychain I found an old credential for another account and I don't know why git was using that one instead of my credential. Deleting the old credential and leave the right one solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, however in Windows OS/10. To fix that, I need to go Credential Manager and I removed all credentials of my old user.

When I run the command on Git Bash:

```
git push origin master
```

I got a screen asking my GitHub credential. After filling the Login/Password, it worked.

Comment: I had the same issue on Windows 7 and I fixed it by removing GitHub account's data from Credential Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today but did not get any answer here. Turns out I had not validated my ssh key. To check if your public key is added to your SSH agent:
`ssh -T git@github.com`
If it is not the correct user add your SSH key using:
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key`